# Materialize collapsible behaving weirdly when used with angular js

Tags: angularjs, materialize

- I am developing an application with *angular js* & *materialize framework*.
- On HTML page side, i have top nav-bar and side nav-bar.
- On the side nav-bar, I have links inside the collapsible.
- Based on the link selection, I will inject partial page in the container.

Problem

- When I inject normal HTML content, then it's working fine.
- But, when I use  directive, which contains partial page, then
  side nav-bar collapsible are automatically getting closed when clicked on it.


  Why this is happening, please help.